# Phaser WebGL warning: texImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi i'm trying to make a game in JavaScript using Phaser. I Go Live in vscode and when i opened the console in browser there was a warning message saying: `WebGL warning: texImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads.` In my code i was trying to create a background, here is my code:

```
const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update  
})

function preload(){
    game.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png')
    game.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png')
    game.load.image('diamond', 'assets/diamond.png')
    game.load.spritesheet('woof', 'assets/woof.png', 32, 32)
}

function create(){
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)

    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky')
}

function update(){}
```

And like i said it gives an error and a black screen. I don't know what to do. I'm on Ubuntu using Firefox to open the game.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise looking elsewhere. Try opening the game in another browser and see if the warning remains.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1400077

As for your other issue, here is what I have done.

In my Scene1.js

```
   this.load.image("menuStatic", "assets/images/Menu.png");
```

In my MenuScene

```
    this.background = this.add.image(0,0, "menuStatic");
    this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
```

My background image is 400x300 which fits the window size.